# Can not configure router to connect 4 PCs in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: router, multiple-computers, cisco-packet-tracer

I am trying to connect 4 PCs via 4231router. I have used Copper Straight Through cable to connect PCs to the router. Since this router model contains only 2 GigabitEthernet ports, I have added the NIM-ES2-4 module to get 4 more GigabitEthernet ports. But while configuring the router, I am getting this error.

[image]

This is my layout:

[image]

I want to keep the layout the same with the same devices. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NIM-ES2-4 provides 4 Layer 2 ports, not Layer 3 as stated from [Cisco 4-Port and 8-Port Layer 2 Gigabit EtherSwitch Network Interface Module Configuration Guide for Cisco 4000 Series ISR](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/interfaces/NIM/software/configuration/guide/4_8PortGENIM.html)

> The following Cisco 4-Ports and 8-Ports Layer 2 Gigabit EtherSwitch Network Interface Modules are supported on the Cisco 4000 Series ISRs:
>
> - 4-port non-POE Layer 2 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Network Interface Module (NIM-ES2-4)
> - 8-port non-POE Layer 2 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Network Interface Module (NIM-ES2-8)
> - 8-port POE Layer 2 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Network Interface Module (NIM-ES2-8-P)

That is why you can't directly assign an IP to the interface as it is not Layer 3. You might consider creating a vlan, set ip for the vlan, then setting interface gigabitethernet 0/2/3 as switchport access to use the vlan.

Comment: Thank you Reddy Lutonadio, it worked!!!